# Specific Questions about Traffic Signal Preemption at Grade Crossings

Tags: rail, traffic-intersections

Several questions, regarding traffic signal preemption at a grade crossing

1. Is the preempt relay, which triggers the preemption sequence,
   located inside the bungalow which houses the grade crossing
   predictor, or is it located inside the cabinet which houses the
   traffic signal controller?
2. It is my understanding that the speed of an approaching train
   determines the length of time that the preemption sequence will be
   provided for. Is that true? And if so, does the crossing predictor
   calculate the train's speed, determine how long the preemption
   should be provided for and then tell the traffic signal controller
   to provide it for that amount of time?